# select distinct returns nil (globalize3)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

`Post.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT author")`
returns
`[#<Post author: nil>, #<Post author: nil>, #<Post author: nil>, #<Post author: nil>, #<Post author: nil>]`.

However SQL request `SELECT DISTINCT author FROM posts;` works as expected.

I'm using globalize3. `Post.select('DISTINCT author').with_translations('en')` returns all records.
Here is it's log:

```
Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts"."id" AS t0_r0, "posts"."description" AS t0_r1, "posts"."position" AS t0_r2, "posts"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "posts"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "posts"."date" 
AS t0_r5, "post_translations"."id" AS t1_r0, "post_translations"."post_id" AS t1_r1, "post_translations"."locale" AS t1_r2, "post_translations"."author" 
AS t1_r3, "post_translations"."description" AS t1_r4, "post_translations"."created_at" AS t1_r5, "post_translations"."updated_at" 
AS t1_r6 FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "post_translations" ON "post_translations"."post_id" = "posts"."id" WHERE "post_translations"."locale" = 'en' 
AND (post_translations.author IS NOT NULL)
```

How can I select only distinct values?

Comment: please post chunk of log with both requests

Comment: updated. this is first request: `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>#<Post author: nil>}):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be this simple:

```
Post.find(:all, :group => author)
```

Update:

Looks like postgres is a little more compliant than mysql, so try this instead:

```
Post.select("DISTINCT ON (author) *")
```

Comment: `Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (post_category_id = 1) GROUP BY author      
PGError: ERROR:  column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (post_category_id = 1) G...`

Comment: added postgres solution to fix group by bug